# ORACLE PHP OCI Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01465: invalid hex number in C:\xampp\htdocs

Tags: php, database, oracle

When i try to insert base64 format code of an image in the oracle db it shows *Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01465: invalid hex number in C:\xampp\htdocs* $image variable is the base64 data. datatype of the column is created in LONG RAW.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO id_images_student(ID, LENGTH, PICTURE, TYPE) VALUES (:stdId, :len, :img, :fType)";
$insData = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($insData, ':stdId', $stdId);
oci_bind_by_name($insData, ':len', $imageLength);
oci_bind_by_name($insData, ':img', $image);
oci_bind_by_name($insData, ':fType', $fileType);
oci_execute($insData);
```

Comment: Set the `type` parameter appropriately? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php

Comment: Is this an app/database you're building yourself (ie, not a 3rd party vendor database). Because if so, you definitely do not want to be using LONG RAW - that is just setting you up for headaches everywhere.  Use  the BLOB datatype.  If it is indeed a 3rd party database and you can't control the choice of LONG RAW, you have my sympathies :-)

Comment: Share the CREATE TABLE statement and some data and we can take a look.    Review https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example